# How to use a typo3 fluid template on multiple pages?

Tags: templates, typo3

my page tree structure looks like this:

ROOT
- PAGE 1
- PAGE 2
--- page a
--- page b
--- page c
- PAGE 3
--- page d
--- page e

I defined a fluidtemplate in the rootpage.
Pages with small letters should use the same extensiontemplate XY of the roottemplate.
How can I assign a Template more than once?

I dont want to assign an extensiontemplate to PAGE 1 and another one to PAGE 3 with the same typoscript in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add a template on a higher level and clear away the unneeded properties on levels further down (basically reversing your concept).

Or you are using the 'Template on next level' property within the template record:

[image]

Either way, try to simplify your template structure, it will save you some hassle down the line.

Comment: "Template on Next Level" in Template "whole record edit menu" was a great hint! I will try that. Thank you!